# Why is there a grey block beside the orange drop down?

Tags: html, css

I have been looking for 2 hours now and can't figure it out, there is a grey block beside the orange drop-down block that I can't get rid of. I maybe think that it can have with the css to do, but I am not that good at coding yet, since I have only codeed for 3 months pls help me.

```css
.dropbtn {
              background-color: orange;
              color: white;
              padding: 16px;
              font-size: 16px;
              border: none;
              cursor: pointer;
          }

          .dropdown {
              position: relative;
              display: inline-block;
          }

          .dropdown-content {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              background-color: #f9f9f9;
              min-width: 160px;
              box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
              z-index: 1;
          }

          .dropdown-content a {
              color: black;
              padding: 12px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: block;
          }

          .dropdown-content a:hover
          {background-color: orange}

          .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
              display: block;
          }

          .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
              background-color: #000000;
          }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="background-color: white">
            <button
          class="dropbtn">name<button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: You did not close the `button` tag. It should be `<button  class="dropbtn">name</button>` a not `<button class="dropbtn">name<button>`

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a closing tag on your button (`</button>`). Try it out fixed below!

```css
.dropbtn {
              background-color: orange;
              color: white;
              padding: 16px;
              font-size: 16px;
              border: none;
              cursor: pointer;
          }

          .dropdown {
              position: relative;
              display: inline-block;
          }

          .dropdown-content {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              background-color: #f9f9f9;
              min-width: 160px;
              box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
              z-index: 1;
          }

          .dropdown-content a {
              color: black;
              padding: 12px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: block;
          }

          .dropdown-content a:hover
          {background-color: orange}

          .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
              display: block;
          }

          .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
              background-color: #000000;
          }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="background-color: white">
            <button
          class="dropbtn">name</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
              <a href="#">name</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me for hours of searching!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</button>` tag for the button that appears prior to your `dropdown-content` elements :

```
<!-- Ensure your button is closed PRIOR to the rest of your content -->
<button class="dropbtn">name</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">name</a>
  <!-- Additional names omitted for brevity -->
</div>
```

Invalid syntax can often generate markup issues like this as the browser won't know when your button "stops" without you explicitly telling it to.